# Is Threading Necessary/Useful?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Basically, I'm wondering if threading is useful or necessary, or possibly more specifically the uses and situations in which you would use it. I don't know much about threading, and have never used it (I primarily use C#) and have wondered if there are any gains to performance or stability if you use them. If anyone would be so kind to explain, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the world of desktop applications (my domain), threading is a vital construct in creating responsive user interfaces. Whenever a time-or-computationally-intensive operation needs to run, it's almost essential to run that operation in a separate thread. Otherwise, the user interface locks up and, in some cases, Windows will decide that the whole application has become unresponsive.

Threading is also a vital tool in animation, audio and communications. Basically, any situation in which you find yourself needing to do several things at once lends itself to the use of threads.

Comment: +1  It's anecdotal, but open Task Manager on any Windows box.  From the View menu, add the Threads column to the Process tab.  What you will then see is that the vast majority of processes (90+% usually) use multiple threads.  On my box, 71 of the 76 (93%) running processes are multi-threaded.

Answer (score 1):

there is definitely no gains to stability :).  I would suggest you get a basic understanding of threading but don't jump to use it in any real production application until you have a real need.  you have C# so not sure if you are building websites or winforms.

Usually the firsty threading use case for winforms is when a user click a button and you want to run some expensive operation (database or webservice call) but you dont want the screen to freeze up . .

a good tutorial to deal with that situation is to [look at the backgroundworker class in c#](http://dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker) as this will give you a first flavor into this space and then you can go from there

Answer (score 1):

There was a time when our applications would speed up when we deploy them on new CPU. And that speed up was by large extent because CPU speed (clock) was incremented by large factors.

But several years ago, CPU manufacturers stopped increasing CPU clocks because of physical limits (e.g. heat dissipation). And instead they started adding additional cores to CPUs.

Now, if your application runs only on one thread it cannot take advantage of complete CPU (e.g. of 4 cores it uses only 1).

So today to fully utilize CPU we must take effort and divide task on multiple treads. 
For ASP.NET this is already done for us by ASP.NET architecture and IIS.

Look here [The Free Lunch Is Over: A Fundamental Turn Toward Concurrency in Software](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/concurrency-ddj.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how threading can improve performance. You have a n numbers that all needed to be added together. In a single threaded application, it will take a n time units to add all of the numbers together for the final sum. However, if you broke your numbers into 2 groups, you could have the same operation running side by side with, each with a group of n/2 numbers. Each would take n/2 time units to find their respective sums, and then an additional unit to find the full sum. By creating two threads, you have effectively cut the compute time in half.

Comment: `Adding` here looks not appropriate example, imho, since `+` is very cheap operation. I think that `video compression` could be a better one.

Comment: Correct, video compression is much heavier than addition. But it is much easier to see that each addition operation is independent and requires no knowledge beyond elementary math to understand the point that there can be drastic gains in execution time. Once the OP understands the basic concept, he can then move to more complicated examples where the size of the time unit is larger.

Comment: Note that the assumption here is that the two threads are running on two different processors. If the threads take turns running on the *same* processor then obviously the total time is *longer* because you have all the same work to do plus the additional work of context-switching between the threads. Ideally you want *one thread per processor* and each thread is going 100% max processor utilization; if you don't have that then either you bought too much machine for the problems you are solving on it, or the processes are gated on something else, like disk or network access.

Answer (score 0):

Technically on a single core processor, there is no such thing as multi-threading, just the illusion that multiple tasks are happening in parallel since each task gets a small amount of time.

However, that being said, threading is very useful if you have to do some work that takes a long time but you want your application to be responsive (i.e. be able to do other things) while you wait for that task to finish. A good example is GUI applications.

On multi-core / multi-processor systems, you can have one process doing many things at once so the performance gain there is obvious :)

Comment: Even on one core threading can speed up application execution much. For example, when you're working with slow 3rd party datasource (ftp, http, hdd, etc).